# How to create rewrites after migrating from wordpress to another blog

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

I've migrated my blog from wordpress to [Octopress](http://octopress.org/), and from one domain to another.

I want to create rewrites from old pages to new ones (old structure is http://domain.old/?p=number). I've created server block for this purpose which contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name .domain.old;
    rewrite .*p=1$ https://domain.new/2011/rebirth/ permanent;
    rewrite .*p=11$ https://domain.new/2011/travelling-salesman-problem/  permanent;
    rewrite .*p=14$ https://domain.new/2011/minecraft-classic-client-with-fly-ability/ permanent;
#   rewrite ^ https://domain.new permanent;
}
```

If I uncomment last string I'm getting `https://domain.new/p=14` for `http://domain.old/p=14` request. If it's commented out, I'm getting some nginx welcome message, but no redirect.

I'm out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

[My current nginx configuration](http://pastebin.com/xtKCT5KA).

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I'm a little confused. If that line is uncommented, isn't it then doing what you want it to do, redirect from old to new?

Comment: Last line redirecting any request to root directory of new blog. I need to redirect posts manually to right location, not just to the home page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) directive can not be applied to a [`$query_string`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24query_string) and can only change [`$uri`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24uri). To achieve what you are trying to do, you can do the following...

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name .domain.old;

  if ( $arg_p = 1 ) {
    return 301 https://domain.new/2011/rebirth/;
  }

  if ( $arg_p = 11 ) {
    return 301 https://domain.new/2011/travelling-salesman-problem/;
  }

  if ( $arg_p = 14 ) {
    return 301 https://domain.new/2011/minecraft-classic-client-with-fly-ability/;
  }

  # other manual redirects
  # ...

  # global redirect
  return 301 https://domain.new;

}
```

**Please** note that [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Comment: `if` is only evil if it contains directives other than those from the rewrite module (rewrite, return, set, etc.).

Comment: I was thinking about this kind of solution, but never seen any examples of use. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mgorven: Agreed.

Comment: @DmitryPaskal Glad to help.